# Copy a vector into a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, copy

Here's the gist. I have a struct with strings, which has a vector that can call up the info in the struct. I want to create a file that I can reference, but in order to do this I need a struct that has chars, with set sizes, and I can't just switch the original struct over to chars. this is what I have:

```
struct PERSON
{
    string fName;
    string lName;
    string Address;
};

struct tmpPERSON
{
    char fName2[50];
    char lName2[50];
    char Address2[50];
};

class addressBook
{
private:
    vector<PERSON> people;
};
```

I need to be able to copy the stored info from my people vector, into my tmpPERSON struct. Anybody have a clue as to how to do this, because I am just lost.

Comment: Can you explain why you have two identical yet separate `struct` defintions?

Comment: Do you know that a `struct` definition is basically just a description of what objects of that type will look like? It seems that you want one `struct` and *two* objects.

Comment: Once you have two objects of the same class, it's just a matter of `obj2 = obj1;`.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up when I did the original post, I typed the same things for the 2 structs. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
for (vector<PERSON>::iterator iter = people.begin(), end = people.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
{
    tmpPERSON tmp;

    strncpy(tmp.fName, iter->fName.c_str(), 50);
    strncpy(tmp.lName, iter->lName.c_str(), 50);
    strncpy(tmp.Address, iter->Address.c_str(), 50);

    // use tmp as needed...
}
```

Comment: I had actually tried a for loop with people[i].fName = temp.fName2;, but this works way better, thanks again!